# Publish internal plugin event jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to make my plugin raise an event on an internal state-change, which should be observable from the "outside". I'm getting frustrated.

What I've tried (in a prototype class object):

```
 _raise_change_event: function() {
        var e = $.Event( 'change', {
            target: this.elem,
            value: this.val()
        });
        $(this).trigger(e);
 }
```

This function is called internally whenever the user interacts with a UI feature on the element. This much works, and I can examine the event object and all is wonderful. However, the event is not propagated to the outside of the plugin.

How I am trying to subscribe to this event:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
     $('#start_time_3').timeSpinner({ time: '09:00' });

     $('#start_time_3').change(function(e) {
          console.log( 'change detected on start_time_3' );
          console.log( e );
     });
 });
```

The event is never seen in this context. What am I missing?

Comment: In the prototypal object, `this` is the object. I.e., it is the plugin itself. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Shouldn't you be binding it to the element and not the object?

Comment: That did it. Duh.  For the record, and future reders: `$(this.elem).trigger(e);` in the `_raise_change_event` function. Thanks @epascarello